# Spring Boot: @TestPropertySource not loaded from imported configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot 1.5.16 in `WebMvcTest` I'm trying to load `test.properties` applying `@TestPropertySource` annotation in order to override some properties in test class.
This works just fine if I put it on test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class ControllerTest {
    ...
}
```

But properties not loaded if I move it to imported configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
@Import(ControllersConfiguration.class)
public class ControllerTest {
    ...
}
```

and `ControllersConfiguration` class is:

```
@TestConfiguration
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class ControllersConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

Can you explain that behavior?

P.S. `@PropertySource` annotation is working in imported configuration, but with lowest precedence than `application.properties`

UPD: To be clear - try to make all test pass here: https://github.com/Javasick/WeirdTestPropertySource

Comment: have you try to put `inheritLocations` for `@TestPropertySource` as `false`?

Comment: Yes, doesn't help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I investigated it yesterday and found that Spring is looking for this `@TestPropertySource` annotation only on:

- Source test class
- Interfaces if test class implements them
- Superclases of this test class
- Inherited annotations

Here part of code from `AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.class` that responsible for it:

```
MergedTestPropertySources mergedTestPropertySources =
        TestPropertySourceUtils.buildMergedTestPropertySources(testClass);
MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig = new MergedContextConfiguration(testClass,
        StringUtils.toStringArray(locations),
        ClassUtils.toClassArray(classes),
        ApplicationContextInitializerUtils.resolveInitializerClasses(configAttributesList),
        ActiveProfilesUtils.resolveActiveProfiles(testClass),
        mergedTestPropertySources.getLocations(),
        mergedTestPropertySources.getProperties(),
        contextCustomizers, contextLoader, cacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate, parentConfig);
```

The method `TestPropertySourceUtils.buildMergedTestPropertySources(testClass)` exactly responsible for finding and extracting location from this annotation. As you can see Spring invoke it only on test class.

So if you want to externalize this annotation you need to create super class and put this annotation and `@Import` on it, or create interface with this annotation, or create your own annotation that will combine two annotation `@Import` and `@TestPropertySource` and put it on your test classes.

Comment: Thx, That the answer I was looking for

Comment: Can you give an example for the "Inherited annotations"?

Answer (score -1):

From JavaDocs:

> Enabling @TestPropertySource @TestPropertySource is enabled if the
>   configured context loader honors it.
>
> Every SmartContextLoader that is a subclass of either
>   AbstractGenericContextLoader or AbstractGenericWebContextLoader
>   provides automatic support for @TestPropertySource, and this includes
>   every SmartContextLoader provided by the Spring TestContext
>   Framework.

**Bottom line is:**

> Typically, @TestPropertySource will be used in conjunction with
>   @ContextConfiguration.

So you should annotate your Test class with `@ContextConfiguration`

Comment: I've tried to put `@ContextConfiguration` and it does not work

Comment: BTW, Test is working, but putting properties in imported configuration - not